# Does Visual Studio enable me to selectively run test cases?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio

How to segregate this?

Say there is a module built with a contract (i.e. implements an interface). This is done so for unit test purposes and extensibility.

Say there is a person (A) in my team skilled at writing unit test cases for the data access module. So his code simply instantiates this interface after loading the appropriate interfaces and assemblies. And that person write test cases using the interface as the core test subject. (Not sure if this is proper word usage).

Another person (B), who is the actual developer of the module, and who is a bit novice with writing code (and doesn't have a huge knowledge of the .net framework). Even he also writes some test cases. S/he writes code for the module as per the specification guidelines put forth by a team lead (as mentioned above).

So A's test cases would be more in line with system goals. But B's test cases are more like exploring the .net framework. For e.g. it may be something like exploring File.Replace. Unless you read the docs about it very well you are likely to think two files lying "anywhere" in the filesystem can be "replaced". However, the docs say otherwise. But say, B, doesn't know about it. He writes test cases to learn about that.

So generalizing on the whole thing, there are two groups of unit test cases. To be able to track effort and performance, and possibly come out with a training plan for B, I'll need both test cases. However, while testing the data access module on the whole, I'd only need to execute A's test cases.

Does Visual Studio enable me to do this? Selectively run test cases. How can I quickly run all of A's test cases only?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on which test library you are using. If you are using MsTest then you can use [TestCategories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286683.aspx).

```
[TestCategory("Nightly"), TestCategory("Weekly"), TestCategory("ShoppingCart"), TestMethod()]
public Void DebitTest()
{
}
```

Similarly if you are using NUnit you can use [Categories](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=category&r=2.2).

```
namespace NUnit.Tests
{
  using System;
  using NUnit.Framework;

  [TestFixture]
  [Category("LongRunning")]
  public class LongRunningTests
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

UPDATE

If you really have to run them in visual studio I would recommend [using playlists](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/new-unit-test-functionality) instead, however I would question the benefit of this. Having to manually check test cases are passing or coverage isn't great as mistakes could be made. You should automate this as part of your build process. I often think that visual studio makes things that it wouldn't recommend (such as this) difficult to do.

I would also suggest that you get person A and person B to pair program together. The skills of the less experienced person will improve faster as person A transfers knowledge to person B and quality should be higher so you will be able to move faster.

Comment: You have to run this from the command prompt? There isn't an ide way of doing so? I mean when you are using Ms test infrastructure in-built in VS?

Answer (score 0):

I think test separation for this purpose is a bad idea. It might undermine morale of the less 
experienced developer. Also, it creates a problem that arises when multiple people modify same piece of test. If you are really worried about this problem, then ensure the tests written by less experienced developer has high enough quality to be considered part of your codebase. Pair programming and code review are great for this. This also gives the developer good dose of feedback he can use to improve himself.

This is generally question of [how high of quality your tests should be](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/154439/quality-of-code-in-unit-tests). And leaving one part of the codebase low-quality is usually not a good idea. Even if you try to mark it clearly.

Comment: Less experienced dev's test code isn't part of codebase per se. It also some form of documentation why he or she chose to write that code. Those test subs will not be reviewed, but the stuff written in the module will be reviewed.